# What is the minimum scope I need when creating a 'New personal access token to create public repositories from Github API?

Tags: command-line, terminal, github-api, repo

I only need to create repositories as a user (not as an organization) with Github API instead of using the browser (https://github.com/settings/tokens/new.)
Should I select 'Full control of private repositories' or just a few items under repo?